# Can a database be in 2NF without being in the 1NF?

Tags: database, theory

I have a hypothetical database I want to normalize.

I want to make it to all the Normal Forms.

Basically, my question is: Can a database be in 2NF without being in 1NF?

For example:

- Made it to the 1NF
- Had nothing to change to make it to the 2NF
- Made it to the 3NF

Comment: From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form): "*A table that is in first normal form (1NF) must meet additional criteria if it is to qualify for second normal form. Specifically: a table is in 2NF if and only if it is in 1NF*"

Comment: Note that BCNF (rather than 3NF) is the first stopping point and is often sufficient since many designs that are in BCNF are also in 5NF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but the reason is that one of the pre-requisites to be in 2NF is to be in 1NF.

> A table is in 2NF **if and only if it is in 1NF** and...

If that detail didn't exist, it could because 1NF relates to each attribute and 2NF relates to keys.

Comment: So, in this hypothetical table, that has no `NF`, when applying the `1NF`, it automatically, fits to the `2NF`, and it wasn't already in the 2NF, right?

Comment: Because theoretically, a table can go to the 3NF without applying the 2NF. I just wanted to know if the correct is to say it already was in the `2NF`, or it automatically fits in the `2NF`.

Comment: no, the first rule to be on ANY nofrmal form is that a table cant be on a X Normal Form unless it is on the X -1 normal form. IF that rule didnt exist, you could yes have tables on different NFs because the other requirements (I dont remmeebr all of them) may no be dependent from the previous form's requirements

Comment: I have expressed my self in the wrong way. I know it HAVE to be in the `X-1 NF` for it to be in the `X NF`. What i meant is when i have a table in the `"0NF"`, make it to the `1NF`, and there is *nothing*  to change for the table to fit in the `2NF`.

Comment: of course there is. How about all the main requirement? "every non-prime attribute of the table is either dependent on the whole of a candidate key, or on another non prime attribute."